# How to select an image from mobile device and set it as the background image, using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

I am creating a mobile application based on fullcalendar feature. i need to set the background image for that calendar page and which can be chosen by the user manually.Can you help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not a "fullcalendar" topic, i would suggest a css solution with use of jQuery - which you have anyway included.

Based on the docu you have a fullcalendar target

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

and a list for background selection

```
<h2>Choose Background :</h2>
<ul id="calendar-background">
    <li data-color="yellow">Yellow</li>
    <li data-color="red">Red</li>
    <li data-color="green">Green</li>
</ul>
```

Use jQuery Event like this :

```
jQuery("#calendar-background li").click(function(){      
    // current li
    var li = jQuery(this);
    // target color
    var color = li.data("color");
    // put color to fullcalendar
    jQuery("#calendar").css("background-color", color);
});
```

You can easily adapt this example for needs, eg change a background-image (background-image:url(yellow.gif)) or use buttons, links....